# No of integral solutions to an equation confusion?

Tags: combinatorics

For an equation like ${ x }_{ 1 }+{ x }_{ 2 }+{ x }_{ 3 }=60$, I am seeing that in some books they are using $( (60 + 4 - 1) C (4) )$ as solution whereas in some book they are using $( (60 + 4 - 1) C (4 - 1) )$ as solution..My doubt is when to use whom ?

Comment: Could you please explain what is $C(4)$?

Comment: It is basically r of nCr (combinatorics)

Comment: Well, you are looking for the number of solutions for the  equation. Am I right? Or you need to find the solutions.

Comment: Yes, i need to count the no of solutions..Am not looking for enumerating them

Comment: No,they are non negative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $x_i$ are non-negative integers, this means determining the number of ways $n = 60$ identical objects (the $60$ units in $60$) can be put into $r = 3$ bins ($x_1, x_2, x_3)$, where a bin can be empty.

The number of ways to do this is $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1} = \binom{62}{2} = 1891$.

Comment: Thanks,It cleared the doubt..:)

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\sum_{x_{1} = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{x_{2} = 0}^{\infty}
\sum_{x_{3} = 0}^{\infty}\delta_{x_{1}\ +\ x_{2}\ +\ x_{3}\ ,\ 60}} =
\sum_{x_{1} = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{x_{2} = 0}^{\infty}
\sum_{x_{3} = 0}^{\infty}\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}
{1 \over z^{61 - x_{1} - x_{2} - x_{3}}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} =
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}{1 \over z^{61}}
\pars{\sum_{x = 0}^{\infty}z^{x}}^{3}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
 \\[3mm] = &\
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}{1 \over z^{61}\pars{1 - z}^{3}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{-3 \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}{1 \over z^{61 - k}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{-3 \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}\delta_{k,60}
\\[3mm] = &\
{-3 \choose 60} = {3 + 60 - 1 \choose 60}\pars{-1}^{60} =
{62 \choose 60} = {62 \times 61 \over 2} = \color{#f00}{1891}
\end{align}